# Performing arithmetic calculations on all possible digit combinations in a list

Tags: python, numpy, functools

I create data in a format like this:

```
initial_data = [
"518-2", '533-3', '534-0',
'000-3', '000-4']
```

I need to perform several operations (add, sub, div, mult, factorial, power_to, root) on the part before the hyphen to see if there's an equation which equals the part after the hyphen.

Like so:

```
#5182
-5 - 1 + 8 = 2 or 5*(-1) - 1 + 8 = 2

#000-3
number, solution, number_of_solutions
000-3,(0! + 0!) + 0! = 3,2

or
000-4,,0
or 
533-3,5 - (3! / 3) = 3,5
```

Every digit in the part before the hyphen can have an opposite sign, so I found this:

```
def inverter(data):

    inverted_data = [-x for x in data]
    res = list(product(*zip(data, inverted_data)))
    return res
```

I'm supposed to create a CSV file like in the example above but I haven't gotten to that part yet and that seems like the easiest part. What I have are several disparate parts that I can't connect in a sensible way:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
from math import factorial

def plus(a, b):
    return a + b

def minus(a, b):
    return a - b

def mult(a, b):
    return a * b

def div(a, b):
    if b!=0:
        if a%b==0:
            return a//b
    return np.nan

def the_factorial(a, b):
    try:
        return factorial(int(a))
    except ValueError:
        return np.nan
        
def power_to(a:int, b:int)->int:
    try:
        return int(a**b)
    except ValueError:
        return np.nan

def root(a:int, b:int)->int:
    try:
        return int(b**(1 / a))
    except (TypeError, ZeroDivisionError, ValueError):
        return np.nan

def combinations(nums, funcs):
    """Both arguments are lists"""
    t = []
    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
        t.append(nums)
        t.append(funcs)
    t.append(nums)
    return list(itertools.product(*t))

def solve(instance):
    instance = list(instance)
    for i in range(len(instance)//2):
        b = instance.pop()
        func = instance.pop()
        a = instance.pop()
        instance.append(func(a, b))
    return instance[0]

def main():
    try:
        # a = [1, 3 ,4]
        a = [int(-5), int(-1), int(8)]
        func = [plus, minus, mult, div, the_factorial, power_to, root]
        combs = combinations(a, func)
        solutions = [solve(i) for i in combs]
        for i, j in zip(combs, solutions):
            print(i, j)
    except ValueError:
        #If there's too many combinations
        return np.nan
```

I'm having trouble transforming the data from the initial_data to inverter to main which currently only works on one example and returns an ugly readout with a function object in the middle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @PersonPr7, is the number after the *hyphen* the expected result for one of the combined operations (as stated in your description) or the number of possible solutions (as stated in your code)??

Comment: So you goal is to find and print all possible equations (in you CSV) or just find the one that matches the desired result?

Comment: The last number (right most) needs to show the total number of solutions:                                ie, ```print(f"{eq}, {str_repr} = {value}, {res}")``` ```res``` needs to be showing the total number of possible solutins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you a lot (tweaks are on you) but it doesn't write in a CSV, I leave that for you to try, just take into account that there are **thousands** of possible combinations and in some cases, the results are really huge (see comments in `main()`).

I've added missing types in function declarations for **clarity** and successful **linting** (compatible with older Python versions).
Also, I think that the function `combinations()` is not needed so I removed it.
In my proposed code, the function `solve()` is the one doing the magic :)

Said all that, here's the full code:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
from math import factorial
from typing import Union, Callable, Tuple, List, Set


def plus(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b


def minus(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a - b


def mult(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a * b


def div(a: int, b: int) -> Union[int, float]:
    try:
        retval = int(a / b)
    except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
        retval = np.nan
    return retval


def the_factorial(a: int) -> Union[int, float]:
    try:
        return factorial(int(a))
    except ValueError:
        return np.nan
    except OverflowError:
        return np.inf


def power_to(a: int, b: int) -> Union[int, float]:
    try:
        return int(a ** b)
    except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
        return np.nan


def root(a: int, b: int) -> Union[int, float]:
    try:
        return int(b ** (1 / a))
    except (TypeError, ZeroDivisionError, ValueError):
        return np.nan


def solve(values: Tuple[int, int, int], ops: List[Callable]) -> list[Tuple[str, int]]:
    # Iterate over available functions.
    combs = list()
    for f in FACTORS:
        # Get values to operate with.
        x, y, z = values
        sx, sy, sz = x, y, z
        a, b, c = f
        # Calculate the factorial for the values (if applicable).
        if a == 1:
            sx = f"{x}!"
            x = the_factorial(x)
        if b == 1:
            sy = f"{y}!"
            y = the_factorial(y)
        if c == 1:
            sz = f"{z}!"
            z = the_factorial(z)
        for ext_op in ops:  # External operation.
            for int_op in ops:  # Internal operation.
                # Create equations by grouping the first 2 elements, e.g.: ((x + y) * z).
                eq_str = f"{ext_op.__name__}({int_op.__name__}({sx}, {sy}), {sz})"
                eq_val = ext_op(int_op(x, y), z)
                combs.append((eq_str, eq_val))
                # Create equations by grouping the last 2 elements, e.g.: (x + (y * z)).
                eq_str = f"{ext_op.__name__}({sx}, {int_op.__name__}({sy}, {sz}))"
                eq_val = ext_op(x, int_op(y, z))
                combs.append((eq_str, eq_val))
    return combs


def inverter(data: List[int]) -> List[Tuple[int, int, int]]:
    inverted_data = [-x for x in data]
    res = list(product(*zip(data, inverted_data)))
    return res


# Data to process.
INITIAL_DATA: List[str] = [
    "518-2",
    '533-3',
    # '534-0',
    # '000-3',
    # '000-4'
]
# Available functions.
FUNCTIONS: List[Callable] = [   # the_factorial() removed, see solve().
    plus,
    minus,
    mult,
    div,
    power_to,
    root
]
# Get posible combinations to apply the factor operation.
FACTORS: Set[Tuple] = set(product([1, 0, 0], repeat=3))


def main():
    cases = 0       # Count all possible cases (for each input value).
    data = list()   # List with all final data to be dumped in CSV.
    print("number, solution, number_of_solutions")
    # Iterate over all initial data.
    for eq in INITIAL_DATA:
        # Get values before and after the hyphen.
        nums, res = eq.split('-')
        res = int(res)
        # Get combinations with inverted values.
        combs = inverter([int(n) for n in list(nums)])
        # Iterate over combinations and generate a list with their many possible solutions.
        sol_cnt = 0         # Number of solutions (for each input value).
        solutions = list()  # List with all final data to be dumped in CSV.
        for i in [solve(i, FUNCTIONS) for i in combs]:
            for j in i:
                str_repr, value = j
                # Some values exceed the 4300 digits, hence the 'try-catch'.
                # The function 'sys.set_int_max_str_digits()' may be used instead to increase the str() capabilites.
                try:
                    str(value)
                except ValueError:
                    value = np.inf
                if value == res:
                    sol_cnt += 1
                solutions.append((eq, str_repr, value))
                cases += 1
        # Iterate over all data gathered, and add number of solutions.
        for i in range(len(solutions)):
            eq, str_repr, value = solutions[i]
            solutions[i] += (sol_cnt,)
            print(f"{eq}, {str_repr} = {value}, {sol_cnt}")
        data.extend(solutions)
        # Print all the solutions for this input.
        print(f"\nThese are the {sol_cnt} solutions for input {eq}:")
        solutions = [s for s in solutions if (type(s[2]) is int and s[2] == res)]
        for i in range(len(solutions)):
            print(f"    {i:4}. {solutions[i][1]}")
        print()
    print(f"\nTotal cases: {cases}")
```

And for the output, note that solutions are printed/formatted using the name of your functions, not mathematical operators. This is just an excerpt of the output generated for the first value in `initial_data` using factorials in the 1st and 3rd digits:

```
number, solution, number_of_solutions
518-2, plus(plus(5!, 1), 8!) = 40441, 12
518-2, plus(5!, plus(1, 8!)) = 40441, 12      
518-2, plus(minus(5!, 1), 8!) = 40439, 12     
518-2, plus(5!, minus(1, 8!)) = -40199, 12    
518-2, plus(mult(5!, 1), 8!) = 40440, 12      
518-2, plus(5!, mult(1, 8!)) = 40440, 12      
518-2, plus(div(5!, 1), 8!) = 40440, 12       
518-2, plus(5!, div(1, 8!)) = 120, 12
518-2, plus(power_to(5!, 1), 8!) = 40440, 12  
518-2, plus(5!, power_to(1, 8!)) = 121, 12    
518-2, plus(root(5!, 1), 8!) = 40321, 12      
518-2, plus(5!, root(1, 8!)) = 40440, 12

...

These are the 12 solutions for input 518-2:
       0. plus(minus(-5, 1!), 8)
       1. minus(-5, minus(1!, 8))
       2. plus(minus(-5, 1), 8)
       3. minus(-5, minus(1, 8))
       4. minus(-5, plus(1!, -8))
       5. minus(minus(-5, 1!), -8)
       6. minus(-5, plus(1, -8))
       7. minus(minus(-5, 1), -8)
       8. plus(plus(-5, -1), 8)
       9. plus(-5, plus(-1, 8))
      10. plus(-5, minus(-1, -8))
      11. minus(plus(-5, -1), -8)

Total cases: 4608
```

Note that **4608 cases** were processed just for the first value in `initial_data`, so I recommend you to try with this one first and then add the rest, as for some cases it could take **a lot** of processing time.

Also, I noticed that you are truncating the values in `div()` and `root()` so bear it in mind. You will see lots of `nan` and `inf` in the full output because there are huge values and conditions like `div/0`, so it's expected.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for answering! You're a genius! I need to show the total number of solutions (if there are any) for a given number. I've tried comparing ```value``` and ```res``` in the inner loop then icrementing a counter if value and res are equal but it doesn't work. Any advice?

Comment: I have updated the code with this count of solutions, it was a bit trickier. Now the number of solutions is added in all combinations for the same input and after processing each input, all possible solutions are shown as well. Let me know if I understood correctly.

Comment: Just note that there are repeated cases due to the logic, e.g.: `plus(-5, minus(1, -8)) = 4` and `minus(plus(-5, 1), -8) = 4` are the same arithmetically speaking. There other similar cases due to decimal truncation (they are not really the same arithmetically), e.g.: `plus(5, div(1, -8)) = 5` and `minus(5, div(1, -8)) = 5`, but I leave this filtering to you (if required). Regards.